# Integration Properties

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx$$

Consider $$f(x) = x, for x\in [-3,1), f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} for x \in [1,3]$$ Evaluate
$$\int_{-3}^3 f(x)dx$$

Now, this is the standard method that I have come across: to break up the integral over intervals of integration from -3 to 1 and from 1 to 3.
ie $$\int_{-3}^3 f(x)dx = \int_{-3}^1 xdx + \int_1^3 \dfrac{1}{x}dx$$

In my opinion, the first integral of RHS should be $$\lim_{\beta \to 1} \int_{-3}^\beta xdx$$

This is because f(x) = x ends at the point 'closest' to 1. At x = 1, the function changes to $$\dfrac{1}{x}$$
Thus, instead of 1 being the upper limit of the interval of integration, the limit has to be taken for the upper limit of the interval of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the given function $f$ is actually continuous, as the left- and right-hand limits of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ are equal to $1$.  Thus, you can also say that $f(x) = x$ for $x$ in the closed interval $[-3, 1]$.

This wouldn't actually be a problem even in the case of a jump discontinuity in your piecewise function.  If you dive down into working with the definition of the Riemann integral, it's not too hard to prove that changing the value of a function at finitely many points will not change the integral.  Thus, you can freely alter the values at the endpoints without changing the value of the integral.

A different way of looking at it is that the function
$$
F(\beta) = \int_{-3}^\beta x\,dx
$$
is a differentiable and therefore continuous function due to one of the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus.  This continuity means that $\displaystyle\lim_{\beta \to 1} F(\beta)$ will always converge to $F(1)$.

Comment: @Better World Informally, changing the value of a function at $k$ points can only change $2k$ of the terms in a Riemann sum (the point might be an endpoint).  Since both functions are bounded, this alteration in the Riemann sum's value can be made arbitrarily small by choosing a fine enough partition.  For a more formal argument, there is Proposition 1.35 in [these course notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf)

Comment: @BetterWorld You need to assume that $f(x)$ is bounded unless you're willing to deal with improper integrals (which may or may not converge in this case).  With the bounded assumption the integral will exist, although I think the proof is at least a little bit involved.

Comment: As per my understanding, this integral will compute the area between the x axis and g(x) between x=0 and x=10. Now, as per[1.5](http://files.vipulnaik.com/math-152/definiteintegralintro.pdf), these values of g(x) at the mentioned points of discontinuity should therefore make no difference to the value of this integral:$$\int_0^{10}xdx$$

Comment: @BetterWorld that sounds reasonable to me

Comment: In that case you would want to do the pieces separately, yes.